# ASP.NET MVC Alternate @URIaction methods in controller linked to radio button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two methods in my asp.net mvc controller which search the google maps Places API to perform an autocomplete action as the user types in text.

In the background I understand that the data-otf-autocomplete function uses JQUERY UI autocomplete in the background to call these methods on the form. I have to be honest and admit I don't fully understand the JQUERY UI piece as I have adapted it from another the OdetoCode sample from the AJAX lesson on Scott Allen's excellent Pluralsight course Building Applications with ASP.NET MVC4 (Great course btw). The original code from Scott's course linked to a local database to return JSON to complete an autocomplete function which I've adapted to connect to the Google MAPS Places API.

Right now I have **two** search boxes each linked to a different methods on the controller. One uses the locality search (best suited to approximate addresses, most rural addresses here in Ireland fall into that category) while another is suitable for exact street addresses.
Is it possible to wire these two up to a radio button control in my view so you have **a single search box** and depending on the radio button option selected (say locality/address) it automatically routes the request to the associated method controller

```
@model IPagedList<RestaurantListViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

    <form method="get" action="@Url.Action("Index")"
          data-otf-ajax="true" data-otf-target="#List">

        <input type="search" name="searchTerm" data-otf-autocomplete="@Url.Action("Autocomplete_Address")" />
    </form>

<form method="get" action="@Url.Action("Index")"
      data-otf-ajax="true" data-otf-target="#List">

    <input type="search" name="searchTerm" data-otf-autocomplete="@Url.Action("Autocomplete_Locality")" />
</form>


@Html.Partial("_Restaurants", Model)
```

Comment: Not easily, You would need to detach the plugin, change the url and re-attach the plugin each time you click a radio button. I suggest an easier approach might be to generate 2 textboxes (one initially hidden) and depending on the selected button, toggle the visibility of the textboxes. If they are both within the same (say) div element, you shoould not even notice the change in the UI

Comment: Thanks Stephen. That approach worked really well. I'll post the updated code as an answer below in case it's useful to someone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fully working code using Stephen Muecke's suggestion

```
@model IPagedList<RestaurantListViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

}

<script type = "text/javascript" >

        function ShowHideDiv() {

            var chkAddress = document.getElementById("chkAddress");
            var inputAddbox = document.getElementById("inputAddress");
            inputAddbox.style.display = chkAddress.checked ? "block" : "none";
            var chkLocality = document.getElementById("chkLocality");
            var inputLocality = document.getElementById("inputLocality");
            inputLocality.style.display = chkLocality.checked ? "block" : "none";
        }


</script>

    <form method="get" action="@Url.Action("Index")"
          data-otf-ajax="true" data-otf-target="#restaurantList">
        <div>
            <input type="search" id="inputAddress" name="searchTerm" data-otf-autocomplete="@Url.Action("Autocomplete_Address")" checked/>
            <input type="search" id="inputLocality" name="searchTerm" data-otf-autocomplete="@Url.Action("Autocomplete_Locality")" />
        </div>

        <label for="chkAddress">
                <input type="radio" id="chkAddress" name="chkType" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
                Search by Address
            </label>
        <label for="chkLocality">
            <input type="radio" id="chkLocality" name="chkType" onclick="ShowHideDiv()" />
            Search by Location
        </label>

    </form>



@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#inputLocality").hide();
            $("#chkAddress").prop('checked', true);
                 });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cant you just have the search box and 2 radio buttons beside it one for each search option.

```
<input type="radio" name="SearchType" value="local" checked>Locality

<input type="radio" name="SearchType" value="exact">Exact Address
```

You just need one form then, posting to a method in the controller, in the method check for the value of the radio button and run your logic based on this.

UPDATE

Razor View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ControllerMethod", "YourController", null, FormMethod.Post))
{
<input type="radio" name="SearchType" value="local" checked>Locality
<input type="radio" name="SearchType" value="exact">Exact Address
```

}

ControllerMethod

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ControllerMethod(FormCollection form)
    {
        var SearchType = form["SearchType"];

           ........
    }
```

Comment: thanks Dez79. I'm open to that approach but I'm just not sure how I would pass in the value of the radio button to the method. Sorry- I know that's quite a basic question.

Comment: see updated solution, you should probably look at tutorials on how to implement forms using the razor syntax

Comment: Thanks Dez79 as Stephen Muecke has intimated that approach has some further complexity so I've taken his alternate approach which I think is more straightforward